# Flagging pop-up screen covered by answer text field

Tags: bug, suggestion

When I'm at work and have free time, I usually spent that time on WPSE anwering or editing or flagging a question.

I'm currently using my phone to do that, which is a Blackberry 9320. I've picked up a bug with the following screen pop-up, "Flagging>This question doesn't belong here because it is"

When you click on the "flag" link beneath a question, the "I am flagging this question because" pop-up screen comes up. Now I select the "it should be closed for another reason..." Option. This options opens the "Flagging>This question doesn't belong here because it is".

This is where the problem is. The answer text area where you enter your answer to the question is displaying on top of the bottom part of the pop-up, so you cannot see the "flag question" button. With this problem I can only mark a post as "off topic" as this opens the "Flagging>Closing>Off-Topic" pop-up screen which displays correctly again.

Can you please fix this problem.

Comment: Same issue here with Windows Phone 7.8 (Nokia Lumia 710)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the last update on the stackexchange network during the run of the last week it seems that this problem have been addressed and fixed as such.

The flagging screen is now dispaying correctly as it should and does not get hidden anymore by any post content.